# Can someone who rsync-s his iTunes music avoid full-fledged exports?

Tags: itunes, music, sd-card, iphone

I'd like to listen to my iTunes music (especially lossless) in the car and on the go.

I was waiting for a 256GB option from Apple, not particularly for the iPhone 7.

With the iPhone 7 it will still be a hassle to pass a digital signal to an amplifier (plus I'm tired of the price tag Apple imposes for just some extra memory).

Suppose I use instead a 256GB microSDXC card, providing the ultimate portability. I understand that by using an SDXC rather than an iPhone (or the less-than-very-interesting iPod Touch) I would lose the `Plays` and the `Last Played` counts. But that's about it.

This has surely been asked many times before. I wish Apple made it possible to sync from iTunes to a device that provides digital audio out (there are several options on the market), but they have zero incentive (and much to lose) by adding such a facility, or even making it easy to do so.

My question is then: The state of the art, as I understand it, in September 2016, is to:

1. Export from iTunes a playlist (one whose size does not exceed the SDXC's capacity).
2. Use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) (which can be easily installed through [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/)) to sync just the changes.

Step 2 is pretty fast. But it's tedious to repeat Step 1. Can one do better?

Comment: @Tetsujin You raise a valid point, but that's orthogonal to my question—it possibly even reinforces the need to save time exporting. So let me ask: suppose you spent the time to downsample a 128 AAC version of your music onto your Mac's disk before using rsync to the SDXC card. How to you avoid repeatedly doing the first step?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm a Mac (and OS X, including iTunes) addict who's contemplating, just contemplating, taking a 2-gram SDXC card with him to the amplifier in the living room via a nice DAC, to the gym with a nice player handling digital files, and to the car with a USB adapter. Can you help?

Comment: I guess not....